# Adding spice to poaching liquid

Tags: spices

I have recently started poaching some of my sausages. I add a spoon of barbeque spice to the hot water when I poach it. The sausage turns out great but I'm left wondering if the spice I add to the water actually adds any flavour? I suspect I might be wasting spoonsful of spice.

So does it achieve anything to add spice to poaching liquid?

Comment: I think you'd have to add more than just a spoonful for it to have a noticeable effect.

Comment: When you say 'poach', are they in deep water the whole time, or are you putting them in water, then boiling the water off?  The second one will result in more favor transfer than the first.

Comment: Can you taste the difference? If not, then you're wasting it.

Comment: I read a lot of recipe sites which state adding herbs/spices etc to pot of water is pointless, however it's not true. If you put enough in, the flavours will seep into the food. Boiled rice with Soy Sauce in the water, and/or Cumin/Turmeric etc. You do have to put more in than you would if it was in direct contact without water. Try 2 spoons next time and see how it goes, adding more each time until you get the flavour strength you want. You use a fair bit more than (say) baking sausages in the oven smothered in BBQ sauce, as the flavouring doesn't have the water to mix in with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A spoon of spice is definitely a waste of spice since there is so little spice in a great quantity of water. If you want to add flavor when you're cooking sausages, you'd either at least triple the quantity of spice or you could rub the sausages in the spice and grill them instead, do you poach them and then grill them ? or do you simply poach them ?

Comment: I just poach them.